# If I'm trying to deploy the CAR in DEV Environment it will work, and when I deploy the same CAR File in another Environment will the components work?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

We will be Developing ESB Service in Integration Studio with all below artifacts.. api, endpoint, inbound-endpoints, message-processors, proxy-services, sequences, tasks, templates and DSS data(Data Source, Query, Operation, Post )

If I'm trying to deploying in DEV Environment.. This will work! and when I deploy the same CAR File in another Environment and do changes in the components (api, endpoint, inbound-endpoints, message-processors, proxy-services, sequences, tasks, templates and DSS data(Data Source, Query, Operation, Resource)) will the changes persist after changing and restarting the Server.

Do let us know what are the artifacts that can persist are provisioned to do changes in CAR file after Deployment though management console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for using the same CAR file to deploy across multiple environments, you can’t edit the artefacts after the deployment, as once the server gets restarted, it will load the files from the CAR and it wouldn’t persist the changes you made after deployment.

An alternate for this would be to use Governance registry and store all the environment specific resources there and keep only static files inside the car file. Please look deep into using registry resources for the same.

In one of my recent projects, I use place holders and property files for build and deployment of the same car file across environments, provided all the place holders would be replaced by the actual values of the properties of the specific environment at the time of build and deployment.

Hope I answered your query.

Links to dig deep - https://www.slideshare.net/wso2.org/managing-esb-artifacts-with-the-wso2-g-reg

https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/development-and-deployment-of-c-app-based-artifacts-on-multiple-environments/